# Transformation from world frame to odom(robots) frame

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey i am new to ROS and Stage. I am simulating a robot to move from one point to other autonomously. The problem is i dont know how to transform from world frame (i.e as soon as you open ROS you get X-Y frame) and odom frame(i.e the frame of robot) So here stage world has one origin and robot(odom) has another origin there is a translation and rotation between them. How can i transform a point from stage world frame to robots odom frame?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196681/transformation-from-world-frame-to-odom(robots)-frame./) by [ruthvik](https://answers.ros.org/users/20314/ruthvik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-11-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2014-11-04**:
Just a note on frame ID: both *map* and *odom* are typically world frames, and *base_link* refers to the body frame of the robot.

http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I highly recommend going through the [TF tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials).

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ruthvik](https://answers.ros.org/users/20314/ruthvik/) on 2014-11-04**:
hey i have gone through them but when i run the command **rosrun tf view_frames** i get the result as below
odom-->base_footprint--->base_link---->base_laser_link
i dnt want any f these trnsfrmtns. I want a trnsfrmtn frm stage world points 2 odom(robots) frames. shud i creat new frame 4 stage world?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-11-04**:
If you want actual stage poses for debugging, stage ros publishes base_pose_ground_truth. You can produce a small program that sends this. Alternatively if you configure odometry without noise it should be the same as ground truth.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To have a transformation from world to odom you need to run a localizer (e.g. http://wiki.ros.org/amcl ), which will provide the missing transformation.

---

Originally posted by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) with karma: 1658 on 2014-11-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1